# Serialization error that I cannot seem to solve

Tags: c#-4.0

here is the xml I receive.

```
<ussd PDU="CTRL" MSISDN="*" STRING="2012/05/06 04:27:06 PM" TID="0" REQID="0"  ENCODING="ASCII" TARIFF="*" STATUS="0"><cookie/></ussd>
```

here is my class structure:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ussd", Namespace = "")]
public class ussd
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "PDU")]
    public string PDU = string.Empty;

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "MSISDN")]
    public string MSISDN = string.Empty;

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "STRING")]
    public string STRING = string.Empty;

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TID")]
    public string TID = string.Empty;

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "REQID")]
    public string REQID = string.Empty;

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ENCODING")]
    public string ENCODING = string.Empty;

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TARIFF")]
    public string TARIFF = string.Empty;

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "STATUS")]
    public string STATUS = string.Empty;
}
```

Why cant this xml be serialized into this class?  Can anyone see something wrong with the xml that i cannot see?

Comment: I think your xml have to look like:<ussd><PDU>CTRL</PDU><MSISDN>*</MSISDN>...</ussd>

Comment: I tested your code and I do not receive any error and the object appears to have all the properties set properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why cant this xml be serialized into this class?

It can:

```
string xml = @"<ussd PDU=""CTRL"" MSISDN=""*"" STRING=""2012/05/06 04:27:06 PM"" TID=""0"" REQID=""0""  ENCODING=""ASCII"" TARIFF=""*"" STATUS=""0""><cookie/></ussd>";

using(StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
using (XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
{

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ussd));
    ussd myobject = (ussd)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);

    Console.WriteLine(myobject.ENCODING);
}
```

> Can anyone see something wrong with the xml that i cannot see?

Only the fact that you're not deserializing the cookie element.